# With regards to sticky intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I understand the implementation of sticky intents, but if I have a sticky intent initially in this form :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("some.custom.action");
intent.putExtra("A", true);
intent.putExtra("B", true);
intent.putExtra("C", true);
sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
```

And later put out a sticky intent in the form of:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("some.custom.action");
 intent.putExtra("A", true);
 intent.putExtra("B", false);
 sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
```

Would the key of 'C' cease to exist or would it remain with the value of true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody that is interested:

The new intent overwrites the previous intent resulting in the extra not existing any more.